# MapThread function from Mathematica in R

Tags: r, function, wolfram-mathematica

coming from Mathematica I started using R. In Mathematica there is a function MapThread. Elements from to different lists are plugged into function. 
Here is a small Example:

`MapThread[#1*#2 &, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]`

Returns:

{4, 10, 18}

I was wondering if there is a identical function in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `mapply` for this:

```
mapply('*', c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
[1]  4 10 18
```

THe first argument is the function to be applied element-wise on the following arguments(in this case multiplication `*`). Then the second argument is the first vector and the third argument is the second vector (on whose elements the function will be applied).

You can see more examples and read about it if you type `?mapply` on the console.

Comment: BTW, the hard way would be `1:3 * 4:6` :-)

Comment: @akrun Thanks Akrun, and definitely a better way for this example :)

Comment: @Roland That's a good one Roland. Don't you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If for some strange reason you can do the obvious, e.g., `c(1,2,3) * c(4,5,6)`, `do.call` would be more efficient than `mapply`: `do.call("*", list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6)))`

I think that's the equivalent of what your Mathematica code does.

Comment: `mapply` is a loop. Try `mapply(function(x, y) {print(x); x * y}, c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))`.

Comment: Yeah I now it is a loop, I just thought it was going to be real fast because it's C based. Cool, I found out something new today.

Comment: You still have one call to an R function for each iteration even if the call ist done by C code.